# Trouble with drawing sf::Text. C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I have trouble with `sf::Text` and `sf::Font`.
The text doesn't want to draw. The `std::wstring` has correct text value. `sf::Font` load perfectly.
Here is my code:

```
sf::Font mainGameFont;
void drawText( const std::wstring& str, const int size, const float xposition, const float yposition, sf::RenderWindow& window, const sf::Font& mainGameFont )
{
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
    source.setFont( mainGameFont );
    source.setColor( color );
    source.setCharacterSize( size );
    source.setString( str );
    source.setPosition( xposition, yposition );
    window.draw(source);
}
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "test");
    mainGameFont.loadFromFile("futura.ttf");
    ...
    //Other code, calling drawText(...), etc
    ...
}
```

Can anyone help me, please? 
Sorry for my bad English.

Updated:
This code isn't working!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

sf::Font mainGameFont;
sf::Text source;
void drawText( const std::wstring& str, const int size, const float xposition, const float yposition, sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Font& mainGameFont )
{
    mainGameFont.loadFromFile("futura.ttf");
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
    source.setFont( mainGameFont );
    source.setColor( sf::Color::White );
    source.setCharacterSize( size );
    std::cout << "stat1" << std::endl;
    source.setString( str );
    source.setPosition( xposition, yposition );
    window.draw(source);
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "Test");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        drawText(L"Ok", 20, 90, 90, window, mainGameFont);
        window.display();
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you remembering to call `Window::display` to switch the back buffer? If you are unfamiliar with this concept [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28075043/1732865) explains it.

Comment: You're querying for events too right?

Comment: @Conduit Yes, I wrote window.display() in the end of main cycle.

Comment: @user975989 I don't understand you very good. With sfml event all good.

Comment: @endless_cycle Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better help you.

Comment: @user975989 I have edit my question.

Comment: @Conduit I have post simple code example to my question. This code isn't working.

Comment: "Updated: This code isn't work :( This code isn't work :(" You need to explain how it's not working. Not working could cover everything from the code not compiling to the code compiling and nothing being rendered.

Comment: @c1646091
This code compile but not render anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, firstly, your entire code reeks of bad programming practices:

You declare:

```
sf::Font mainGameFont;
sf::Text source;
```

As globals, but then violate shadowing rules by using the exact same names for variables in the function:

```
void drawText( const std::wstring& str, const int size, const float xposition, const float yposition, sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Font& mainGameFont )
```

Mainly by redeclaring:

```
sf::Font& mainGameFont
```

You then mindboggingly pass the global variable that the function can already see... as a reference to the function:

```
drawText(L"Ok", 20, 90, 90, window, mainGameFont);
```

You also incorrectly use the reserved keyword 'size':

```
source.setCharacterSize( size );
```

Which you cannot use the name of.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::Text source;
sf::Font mainGameFont;

void drawText( const sf::String &str, const int Size, const float xposition, const float yposition, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    source.setString(str);
    source.setCharacterSize(Size); //only the lower cased word size is reserved. A capital S fixes that.
    source.setPosition(xposition,yposition);
    window.draw(source);
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "Test");

    //This should only be called ONCE, not at every pass.
    mainGameFont.loadFromFile("futura.ttf");
    source.setFont(mainGameFont);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        drawText("Ok", 20, 90, 90, window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Re-written to work.

Comment: Thanx you very much! Now it is work and draw "Ok", but crash in the end. But it is not a big problem, I'll fix it.

Comment: Lol, I trying to rewrite this code to my game, but it is not draw noting! Then I try to change 
    source.setColor(color);
to
   sourve.setColor(sf::Color::White);
And it is work perfectly! Big thanks to you!

Comment: To be correct, the proposed code should 1) not use SFML types as globals and 2) handle events periodically. Both of these issues make this code enter the undefined behaviour land.

Comment: Is "size" really a c++ keyword or are you thinking of "sizeof"?